# How to display data from a database in html

Tags: php, html, database, mysqli, html-table

I'm trying to pull my information from the database, which I've managed, and store it in a table. However I keep getting errors. Can anyone see the problem?

```
<?php
//Make connection to database
$connection = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'c3438525');
//Display heading

//run query to select all records from customer table
//store the result of the query in a variable called $result

//Use a while loop to iterate through your $result array and display
//each field wrapped in appropriate HTML table tags.



//include 'connection.php'  

include 'products.css'
$query="SELECT * FROM products";

$results=mysqli_query($connection, $query);

while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($results)){

    ?>



<table class='display'>
<tr><td><?php echo "<img src=$rows[$product_image] height='200px' width='200px'>"  ?></td></tr>

<tr>
<td><b><?php echo "$rows[$product_name]" ?></td>
<td><b><?php echo "Price: £ $rows[$price]" ?></td>
<td><b><?php echo "Picture: $rows[$product_image]" ?></td>

</tr>


</table>
    <?php   
}
?>
```

Comment: Missing semi-colon for one thing `include 'products.css'` but that's most likely a typo.

Comment: *"However I keep getting errors."*- Being?

Comment: @Fred-ii- Is it possible to include css file using php?

Comment: @Indra Sure, but I wouldn't put it there. That belongs in `<head></head>` if anything.

Answer (score 1):

You need to provide the array keys as strings and also terminate statements with a semicolon.

```
<table class="display">
<tr>
    <td>
    <?php
       // you can also write an array value directly into a string
       echo "<img src=\"{$rows['product_image']}\" height=\"200px\" width=\"200px\">";
    ?>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><b><?php echo $rows['product_name']; ?></b></td>
    <td><b><?php echo "Price: £ " . $rows['price']; ?></b></td>
    <td><b><?php echo "Picture: " . $rows['product_image']; ?></b></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

In addition you should be closing those `</b>` tags (but `<strong>` tags are preferred over `<b>`)

It is a better practice to include styles in the `<head>` of the document

```
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="products.css">
</head>
```

but `include 'products.css';` will work (can't forget those semicolins)

Answer (score 0):

Here your `img` `src` is considering as string not variable. There is no terminating semi clone at the end of `echo`. Just change it.

```
<table class='display'>
    <tr><td><?php echo '<img src="'.$rows[$product_image].'" height="200px" width="200px">';  ?></td></tr>
                                 //^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^//
    <tr>
        <td><b><?php echo "$rows[$product_name]"; ?></td>
        <td><b><?php echo "Price: £ $rows[$price]"; ?></td>
        <td><b><?php echo "Picture: $rows[$product_image]"; ?></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Also suggest you `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="products.css">` instead of `include 'products.css'`